# Box2D how to detect touching elements

Tags: android, box2d

I am trying to build a game using Box2D.

My problem is: on each update of the engine, I need to check each element and update the state of the element according to the state of touching elements. So I really need a function to detect which element is touching which element.

How can I do that?

Edit:
Example-> i have 5 boxes and box1-box2-box3 are touching to each other and box4-box5 are touching each other. And without any change on collusions if state of box2 changes to blue, box1 and box3 should also become blue

Comment: Are you using the NDK verion of Box2D or JBox2D libraries ?

Comment: i am using libraries that i import in android studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to implement ContactListener in a class and use it's methods  :

```
public class CollisionListener implements ContactListener {

    @Override
    public void beginContact(Contact contact) {


    }

    @Override
    public void endContact(Contact arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void postSolve(Contact arg0, ContactImpulse arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void preSolve(Contact arg0, Manifold arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

You can set the listener like this

```
world.setContactListener(new CollisionListener());
```

Every time two item contact, beginContact(Contact contact) will be called and you will get info in the Contact object about which two items are colliding. You can access them like this

```
if ( contact.getfixtureA.getBody().getUserData() == "element1" &&
    contact.getfixtureB.getBody().getUserData()=="element2" ){
    Colliding = true;
}
```

Comment: problem is i have a lot of elements of same type created dynamicly during the game. And i really need to know the exactly ehich element is touching.

Comment: When you create your bodies with BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef(); before you add them to the physics world, you can set and object for userdata like this :  bodyDef.userData = data; to set a unique identifier for each one.

Comment: I know that. but my problem is that i need to place my algorith not in collusion. Assume that i have 5 boxes colliding.box1,2,3 colliding with each other and box 4,5 colling with each other. I press a button and box2 will turn blue. My algorithm should detect that box1 and box3 is colliding with box2 so they should also turn to blue. But box4 and 5 does not turn to blue becouse they dont have any connection with any other blue box

Comment: OK, so you want to detect collision on an event such as a user pressing a button. Originally the question asked said "a function to detect which element is touching which element" ~ You can do this by using ContactEdge ce = my_body.getContactList(); and then calling ce.contact.isTouching() to compare.

Comment: There is nothing colled ContactEdge nor a method like getContactList() !!

Comment: import org.jbox2d.dynamics.contacts.ContactEdge;

Comment: seems like i am not using jbox :((( i just added andenginebox.jar file. what is jbox and how can i use it with android studio?

Comment: OK, you're using AndEngine with the Box2D extensions. I just included jbox2d-library-2.1.2.jar into my libs (in Eclipse) and am using it without any game engine so you might need specific AndEngine functions and methods. btw, the whole Box2D development is so splintered across different ports and game engines so the documentation is difficult.